# What does 被熏 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

So I'm not sure if I'm correct but I want to make sure, does this 被熏 mean sick? According to google translate this 被熏 means "smoked", but in the context of the sentence, it doesn't really make sense to me. I searched it up a bit, and 被熏 could mean both getting sick and suffocating from smoke according to people, but I just wanted to make sure.

The full context:

苏小钰展颜一笑，带着满嘴的油渍，打招呼。(Understand)
扑面而来的冲击味道让杜方面色微微僵硬。(Understand)
落落(Name)歪着脑袋看着苏小钰，脸上的笑容，愈来愈……浓郁。(Understand)
爸鼻(Name)好像被熏到了呢…… (This sentence doesn't make sense to me)
要不要抽下阿姨。(I think I understand this sentence, but not sure)

My translation:
Su Xiaoyu greeted with a smile, her mouth full of oil stains.
The rushing smell caused Du Fang's face to slightly stiffen.
LuoLuo tilted her head and looked at Su Xiaoyu, the smile on her face became more and more intense.
Dad Nose seems to be sick....
Do you want to smoke(burning someone alive?) the aunt?

More context:

“吃早餐？”

“早餐就嗦味道这么重的粉啊？”

杜方勉强一笑。

苏小钰哈了口被辣红的唇，笑道：“对的呢，老早就在小区门口等杜哥了，肚子饿，就先整一碗粉嗦着。”

苏小钰似乎接受了命运，心态平和很多，很快代入了身为助理的角色中。

“嗦的好……下回别嗦了。”

杜方想了想，指了指落落，说道：“落落说小摊边的螺蛳粉……不干净，容易吃坏肚子。”

苏小钰脸上的笑容顿时一僵。

落落……

嗦粉的快乐，突然就没有了。

终究抵不上那被支配的恐惧。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

熏: ***be poisoned or suffocated by (usually something smelly)***

In the context, we can infer from 苏小钰展颜一笑，带着满嘴的油渍，打招呼 that the odour comes from 苏小钰's mouth. He/she might have eaten something smelly. It gathered the father seemed to have suffered from that odour(好像被熏到了呢).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, then would 要不要抽下阿姨 mean "Do you want to choke the auntie"?

Comment: @Huy I don't quite understand that sentence in the context. Maybe, more context could help.

Comment: I've made an edit and added more context, it continues right after 要不要抽下阿姨.

Comment: @Huy The book introduced some dialectal usage here. 抽 in that dialect should have a special meaning I guess.

Answer (score 1):

扑面而来的冲击味道....好像被熏到了 = 好像被扑面而来的冲击味道熏到了

Similar to the effects of standing near a smoky fire, here, 熏 can be interpreted as "choking/choked" (by the stinky smell).

要不要抽下阿姨. Depending on the storyline, "抽" can mean "smoke" (if he's a smoker), give her an (affectionate) "slap", or even mean "kiss her".

Both words can't be translated directly from their original meaning, but from sensemaking through association.

Comment: Oh thank you for clarify the last part!